# Files that start with ' ~$ ' and end with .doc / .docx are appearing on my desktop. How can I remove them?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, microsoft-word, unix

I was going through my desktop in Linux and I noticed a list of files that were not on my desktop. They are Microsoft word(.doc & .docx) files that exist on my computer elsewhere. For some reason they are showing up on my desktop(in UNIX environment). They start with '~$' and the first two letters of file names are cut off. For example if the file name is filename.docx, it would show as ~$lename.docx. How can I remove these files?

Comment: Did you _previously_ have those Word documents on your desktop?

Comment: @grawity Yes it is possible that some of them have been on my desktop in the past, some of them are over two years old. From my research, I have seen that Microsoft Word stores backup hidden files like these for emergency. It just bugs me that they are showing up in my UNIX environment.

Comment: @Scott I have tried doing `$ rm ~$lename.docx` but I got a message saying `rm: No such file or directory.` The same with `$ rm filename.docx` and `$ rm lename.docx`

Comment: If you copied your entire desktop from a Windows system, why wouldn't they show up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `rm ~$lename.docx`, the shell sees `$lename` and tries to expand it to the contents of the likely non-existent variable `lename`, so the command ran is actually something like `rm ~.docx`. You'll have to quote it so that the shell doesn't try to do that:

```
rm '~$lename.docx'
```

Alternatively, if you have multiple such files, you can use shell globbing (wildcards), assuming all such filenames begin with `~$` and end with `docx`:

```
rm ~$*.docx
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. It worked by doing `rm *.docx` and `rm *.doc`, it didn't need the `~$` for some reason. Thanks alot!

Comment: @AladdinAl-Khatib without the `~$`, if you had a normal `lename.docx` file, that would have been deleted too. If you didn't have any of those, `*.docx` is fine.

Comment: @AladdinAl-Khatib: The `~$` is not a magic prefix; it is just part of the actual file name. It doesn't affect the way wildcards work.

Comment: Worth noting that single quotes `'` matter. Your shell will likely interpolate double quotes `"` meaning it will treat `$` as a variable and you'll get a response from rm that no such file exists.

Answer (score 0):

The doc/docx file whose name starts with ~$ is temproray file created by Microsoft Word. If you use Windows PC, you can see that a transparent doc/docx icon appears on your desktop once you make an edit to your doc/docx file on your desktop.

In some situations, Microsoft Word maybe has an error to not remove this temporary file automatically. So if you find there is such a file in your desktop folder, you can remove it by using `rm '~$<your filename>'`. You must add quote marks because your filename can contain some special symbols and spaces.

Hope that this can help you all.